# Construction of functions in mean value theorem problems

Tags: calculus

$f$ is a function and it's second derivative is continuous on $[a,a+h]$
Show there exists a positive $t$ less than 1 such that.

$$ f(a+h)-f(a) -0.5h(f'(a)+f'(a+h))+(h^3/12)f''(a+th)=0$$

I tried using the function 
$$ g(t)=f(a+th)-f(a) -0.5ht(f'(a)+f'(a+th))+(t^3h^3/12)A$$
This gives $g(1)=g(0)$ and I try to apply Rolle theorem, but that doesn't simplify. My guess is I need to take a slightly different function.

Also, can someone tell me some guidelines I need to keep in mind while constructing the $g$ function.